# Multisite custom post type's single page 404

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite, 404-error

I have two sites in my multisite setup - `domain.tld` (site A) and `domain.tld/lifestyle` (site B). This is my first multisite attempt.

I've made a widget that creates a custom post type "`latest-news`" with `WP_Query` and I call the widget via `dynamic_sidebar()` within a page template `page-news.php`, which matches up with my static page News. The widget is only enabled on site A.

You can see all files set up here, including my `.htaccess`:
https://gist.github.com/e97812f6d5c12d16039d

The posts display correctly, but when I go to view a single post I get a 404.
The URL I get is

`domain.tld/blog/latest-news/news-item-1 <-- Does not work`

instead of

`domain.tld/latest-news/news-item-1 <-- Does work`

Now I know that the first site is supposed to have `/blog/` in the URL, but this is the first instance where I've seen it on my site, all other pages don't seem to have it.

Does anyone know how to:

1. remove the `/blog/` portion **without removing it from the Network admin**, or
2. get it to work with the `/blog/` portion?

I've reset the permalinks many times, going between my custom `/%category%/%postname%/` and default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12002

`/blog/` is added to prevent permalink clashes on the root site of a multisite install. For now you're going to have to resort to using the network admin and manually wading through the options table modifying it each time you regenerate rewrite rules.

> You can remove the blog slug completely.
>
> Go into the primary site options in the network admin, and set your permalinks without blog included, to something like /%postname%/. Go back to the permalinks settings in your site's dashboard, you should notice that /blog is removed from the permalinks. Set them to your desired structure again and save.
>
> This should remove the blog slug from your URLs.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-remove-blog-slug-for-resolving-multisite-url-confusion#post-1990227

Comment: Damn, I was hoping there was another way since everytime either myself/other developer/client update permalinks on site A, it will reset. Thanks for your answer :D